# Get value within the same sub array [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["EAN"]=>
    string(13) "1234567890123"
    ["Price"]=>
    string(5) "99.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["EAN"]=>
    string(13) "2234567890123"
    ["Price"]=>
    string(6) "199.00"
  }
}
```

I would like to:

1) Find one of these sub arrays using the EAN value

2) And return the related price for this specific EAN

So for example the function *getPrice('2234567890123')* should return *199.00*.

What should be the code for the function getPrice?

Comment: We're not gonna write the code for you, show us what you have tried and what errors you ran into.

Comment: make a loop and look for the value of `EAN` and then test your condition if matched then store the `Price`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
<?php
$array = array(
"0"=>
    array(
        "EAN"=>"1234567890123",
        "Price"=>"99.00"
    ),
"1"=>
    array (
        "EAN"=>"2234567890123",
        "Price"=>"199.00"
    )
);

$key = array_search('1234567890123', array_column($array, 'EAN'));
echo $array[$key]['Price'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * this generates a multi dimensional array of products
 * a multi dimensional array means arrays within arrays
 * so to access the inner array (EAN => '12345...')
 * we need to loop through the outer array (0 => [EAN => '12345...'])
 */
$products_array = [
    0 => [
        'EAN'   => '1234567890123',
        'Price' => '99.00',
    ],
    1 => [
        'EAN'   => '2234567890123',
        'Price' => '199.00',
    ],
];

/**
 * here is the function, it takes two arguments
 * the products array and the ean number you want to get the price of
 */
function getPrice($products_array, $ean)
{
    // we loop through the array using a foreach loop.
    foreach ($products_array as $key => $product) {
        // now product is just a single level array
        // we can access the ean by
        // typing $product['EAN'] and the Price by
        // typing $product['Price']
        if ($product['EAN'] === $ean) {
            return $product['Price'];
            // When there is a match the function returns the result and exits the loop
        }
    }
}

/**
 * here we are calling the function an giving it two things
 * 1 - the array we want to loop through and
 * 2 - the EAN number that we want to get the price of
 * don't forget to echo the output!
 */
echo getPrice($products_array, '2234567890123');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to achieve desired output.

```
//getPrice method which accepts two parameters $products array and $ean number
function getPrice($products,$ean){
    //iterate $products array to get its elements
    foreach($products as $product){
      //if $procust arrays element EAN matches with $ean number we provide
      if($product['EAN'] == $ean){
      //than return its price
        return $product['Price'];
     }
  }
}


//products array
$products = array(
    '0'=>
     array(
       'EAN'=>'1234567890123',
       'Price'=>'99.00'
     ),
    '1'=>
    array (
      'EAN'=>'2234567890123',
      'Price'=>'199.00'
   )
 );

//EAN value which you need to pass and get its corresponding price
$ean = '2234567890123'; 

//call getPrice function and save the return output value in a $price variable which you can use anywhere
$price =  getPrice($products, $ean);

//print the value by echo $price to verify the required output.
echo $price;
```